# AWS Cloudformation Stack stuck in "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS" status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

It has been 10 days as this stack stuck in current state. The Delete button is not available. It happened after an error occurred in a nested stack and that stack was deleted separately from the parent stack (just assumption). Right now in basic plan which doesn't allow creation of support tickets, is upgrading and contacting the support only way to resolve this issue or there is something else can work for me? Thank you!

*PS. attaching the screenshot*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the awscli to delete the stack? What does it report?

Comment: You can contact Customer Service (which is different to Support), but they would likely recommend that you activate Support for this incident. They might credit-back the costs if you explain the situation.

Comment: This has happened to me on several occasions. When you look at the events on the MIcroserviceStack[1-3] what resources is it stuck on? I fixed two of my issues by replacing an IAM role that was deleted and fixing an overwritten failing docker image.

Comment: @jarmod it gives me error "An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DeleteStack operation: Stack [xyz] cannot be deleted while in status UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS"

Comment: @GeorgeRushby No errors in nested stacks but in parent stack. The error is referencing to a table in the nested stack that has been already deleted (there was a 4th nested stack that was deleted). That's weird that we do not have force-delete option even from admin console, or if nested stack removal causes this error we should not be allowed to remove the nested stack.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah seems the only option is to pay :)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein there is a dropdown to view deleted stacks in the console. Maybe there is something there.

Comment: I've started paying for dev support for this very reason.

Comment: Pay attention to the console output from `sam deploy`. Or look on the events tab.  Without this information it is impossible to tell what went wrong in your stack.  You likely tried to remove a non empty resource (like an s3 bucket)